# Using Ionic 5 and angular on client side and Flask on server side, how do I encrypt my http URL parameters?

Tags: angular, security, flask, ionic-framework

In my mobile app, I'm making a request to my rest API, and in the URL Parameters, I pass the mobile device UUID and the latitude/longitude coordinates. The URL looks something like http://localhost:8100/home. But the requests to the server logs this:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Jun/2021 17:29:21] "?[37mGET /getUser/374f5e06-2caa-sd323-234s-3f52a5e9ec9f HTTP/1.1?[0m" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Jun/2021 17:29:21] "?[37mGET /getPosts/41.723404/-13213.1452344/374f5e06-2caa-4411-b398-3f52a5e9ec9f?forceload=true HTTP/1.1?[0m" 200 -
```

How do I pass in these three values (uuid, latitude, longitude) to the server so that someone doesn't try to intercept them?

HTTPS obviously would do the job but I haven't been able to find anything good on how to implement it into my client side code which uses angular and Ionic.

I was thinking, maybe I should just encrypt these values before sending them, but how exactly does this work? Do I encrypt on client side with some library, then decrypt on the server side using the same library? I've only just started my computer science security class, so I'm still pretty new to all this. I'd appreciate anything, thanks!

#########CLIENT SIDE CODE##########

```
getPosts(latitude: number, longitude: number, user_id: string): Observable<{post_list: IPost[], react_list: IReact[]}>{
    let params = new HttpParams();
    params = params.append('forceload', "true");
    return this.http.get<{post_list: IPost[], react_list: IReact[]}>(this.url +"getPosts/"+latitude+"/"+longitude+"/"+user_id, {params: params});
  }
```

#########SERVER SIDE CODE##########

```
#Posts whithin distance and sorted by Likes
@app.route("/getPostsSorted/<latitude>/<longitude>/<user_id>", methods = ['GET'])
def getPostsSorted(latitude, longitude, user_id):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return (filterPosts(latitude,longitude, 0, user_id))
```

Comment: as long as the application running your app is a browser, https is handled by it. Angular does not provide the transport mechanism, only a wrapper "HttpClient" to handle the browser's http capabilitiies.

Comment: use `POST` method to send data from app to your server.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I found out that you really can't make URL parameters secure. So instead I just used http Headers instead, with this video as a guide (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z83KBAoyNWw)

Now I just need to find a way to incorporate Https with heroku on certain requests and we should be good!